# How to enable nagios user created by yum to use check_by_ssh

Tags: ssh, monitoring, yum, remote, key-authentication

I've used `yum install nagios` on an Amazon Linux instance, and it created a nagios user with shell `/sbin/nologin` and homedir `/var/spool/nagios`. This is the behaviour on EC2.

I want to use `check_by_ssh` running locally as user `nagios` to execute a command on the remote host as some user, without typing in a password. So using `ssh-keygen` seems logical, but how do I generate a public key for user `nagios` if that user doesn't have a shell?

Is the answer to change the default shell (e.g. to bash) and perhaps the homedir of local user `nagios` so I can generate the key, or is there another way?

- Question: Is it bad practice to allow the `nagios` user to login?
- Question: Is it bad practice to change the homedir, e.g. to /home/nagios?
- Question: What is the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: You can login as another user (even if that user doesn't have a shell) using `su -ls /bin/bash username` if you have the password (or are root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `su -c 'ssh-keygen -N ""' nagios` to generate the key pair, or alternatively generate the key pair as another user then copy it in place into `~nagios/.ssh`. Then run `su -c 'ssh-copy-id someuser@remote-host' nagios` to install the public key on the remote machine.

You can change the `nagios` user's home directory if you like, but I don't see the point.

There's no need to change the `nagios` user's shell for what you require here.

Comment: Would +1, but don't have the rep required yet. Thanks.